# MySQL: Subquery in the FROM Clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a view but I keep getting an error saying Subquery in the FROM Clause

need to create a view of these

```
SELECT EPC_ploc, COUNT(EPC_ploc)
FROM P_HAS_LOC
GROUP BY EPC_ploc
HAVING COUNT(EPC_ploc) =
(   
    SELECT MAX(mycount)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT EPC_ploc, COUNT(EPC_ploc) mycount
        FROM P_HAS_LOC
        GROUP BY EPC_ploc
    ) AS mycountt
)
```

and

```
SELECT Category_ID_h, COUNT(Category_ID_h)
FROM P_HAS_CA GROUP BY Category_ID_h
HAVING COUNT(Category_ID_h) = 
(   
    SELECT MAX(mycount)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Category_ID_h, COUNT(Category_ID_h) mycount
        FROM P_HAS_CA
        GROUP BY Category_ID_h) AS mycountt
    )
)
```

Comment: you need to rewrite those queries as joins, rather than subqueries. if you want them in a view.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: it'll be `View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause`

Comment: @lee Please review my answer below and mark correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rework the subquery in your query, which is causing all the problems.  You should be able to get away with this:

```
SELECT EPC_ploc, COUNT(EPC_ploc)
FROM P_HAS_LOC
GROUP BY EPC_ploc
HAVING COUNT(EPC_ploc) =
(   
    SELECT COUNT(EPC_ploc)
    FROM P_HAS_LOC
    GROUP BY EPC_ploc
    ORDER BY COUNT(EPC_ploc) DESC
    LIMIT 1;
)

SELECT Category_ID_h, COUNT(Category_ID_h)
FROM P_HAS_CA
GROUP BY Category_ID_h
HAVING COUNT(Category_ID_h) = 
(   
    SELECT COUNT(Category_ID_h)
    FROM P_HAS_CA
    GROUP BY Category_ID_h
    ORDER BY COUNT(Category_ID_h)
    LIMIT 1;
)
```

As @pala_ mentioned, you could also rework your queries using `JOIN`s, but what I have given above is one correct way to use a subquery to obtain the max value of all your groups.